# EntityFrame work connection string issue

Tags: silverlight, connection-string, datasource, remote-server

I am working on a Silverlight application. during development I have been working with a copy of our production database on my local machine.

When setting up the project I created a model of the local database, and then created a domain service of that model to interact with the data. This is all working well. Now I need to test my product against the live server, but I can not seem to figure out the connection string.

Currently the connection string looks like this.

```
<add name="UserDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.UserDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.UserDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=RTRP20112_NATP_UserData;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The only differance between the database I have been using locally, and the production database is its location. I have attempted to simple replace the data source portion of the connection string with the correct address, and login info but that does not work. I have also duplicated the connection string used by another application to connect to this database, but that does not work since it is missing all the metadata junk(i think). I am not sure how to proceed.

The connection string used by other programs to connect to the server is

```
<add name="UserDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=*.*.*.*,*;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=RTRP20112_NATP_UserData;User ID=*;Password=*;"         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I have tried a few variations of the two as a connection string, most recently I am using.

```
 <add name="UserDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.UserDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.UserDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*.*.*.*,*;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=RTRP20112_NATP_UserData;User ID=*;Password=*;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The most recent error is: Load Error

System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException:Load operation failed for query 'GetUsers'. The undelying provider failed on Open.

Comment: Please give more details on "taht does not work".  Do you get an exception?  Can you connect to the server outside of your app, like with SSMS?

Comment: Sorry for the spelling error, I do get an error when attempting to connect. I will add the information to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured/created ASPNETDB ?

Comment: Yes I have, it seems to be an issue with the connection string itself.

Comment: Is your ASPNETdb in the App_Data folder? Make sure you are able to connect to it from SQL Management Studio. If not, see #2 on this URL http://www.studiocoast.com.au/knowledgebase/6/aspnet/using-sql-server-instead-of-aspnetdbmdf.aspx